# Strange error in running CPP file

Tags: dependencies, compiling, gcc, c++, c

I created a very simple file in CPP, namely `trash.cpp`. Ran it using `gcc trash.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    try{
        throw 6;
    }
    catch(int e) {
        std::cout << "Int exception thrown " << std::to_string(e) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It is showing very strange error. I dont know what to search for, so I'm posting my problem here.

```
aman@aman-Vostro-3578:~$ gcc trash.cpp
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o: In function `main':
trash.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `typeinfo for int'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `std::cout'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
trash.cpp:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
trash.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
trash.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
trash.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
trash.cpp:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
trash.cpp:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>(int (*)(char*, unsigned long, char const*, __va_list_tag*), unsigned long, char const*, ...)':
trash.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx12__to_xstringINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEET_PFiPT0_mPKS8_P13__va_list_tagEmSB_z[_ZN9__gnu_cxx12__to_xstringINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEET_PFiPT0_mPKS8_P13__va_list_tagEmSB_z]+0x113): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx12__to_xstringINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEET_PFiPT0_mPKS8_P13__va_list_tagEmSB_z[_ZN9__gnu_cxx12__to_xstringINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEET_PFiPT0_mPKS8_P13__va_list_tagEmSB_z]+0x159): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx12__to_xstringINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEET_PFiPT0_mPKS8_P13__va_list_tagEmSB_z[_ZN9__gnu_cxx12__to_xstringINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEET_PFiPT0_mPKS8_P13__va_list_tagEmSB_z]+0x186): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider::~_Alloc_hider()':
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_Alloc_hiderD2Ev[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_Alloc_hiderD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char*, void>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&)':
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC2IPcvEET_S7_RKS3_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC5IPcvEET_S7_RKS3_]+0x25): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_local_data()'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC2IPcvEET_S7_RKS3_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC5IPcvEET_S7_RKS3_]+0x3a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider::_Alloc_hider(char*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o: In function `void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::forward_iterator_tag)':
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x56): undefined reference to `std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x8f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xa1): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data(char*)'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xb4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_capacity(unsigned long)'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xc0): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xd6): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char*, char*)'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xe9): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length(unsigned long)'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x103): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x10f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x114): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
trash.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x11c): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref._ZTIi[DW.ref._ZTIi]+0x0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for int'
/tmp/ccffWxA1.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A very rough guess says, that I have f'd up with my dependencies.

Please have a look.

[Edit] 
Plus, another rough guess is, maybe I need to include, libraries externally to GCC. Not sure though.
[Edit]
A very dumb question though.

Comment: Your program runs in C++ without errors, so its logic is right. Rewrite the code in C and it will run with gcc. Or convert the code from C++ to C: [How to convert C++ Code to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/).

Comment: I think this question is not required. 
Can I delete it?

Comment: Yeah, dude thanks. Believe me, I'm not that bad. 
Just having a very rough day.

Comment: The rubbish topic needs some moderation. You are not *running* a .cpp file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to compile it with a **C** compiler, not **C++**. To compile using a C++ compiler, try this command:

```
g++ trash.cpp
```

Comment: I believe that was a very dumb question.
Thanks though. Everyone. 

Was having a very rough day.